# Stored procedure to find Peaks Separated by Seven Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcode

What could be the SQL Server stored procedure to select the highest three peaks separated by seven days.

I have tried the below code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPeaksAndInsertIntoPeakFact 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Initialize starting date
    DECLARE @currentDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(dateTime) FROM Peak);   

    -- Initialize peak type
    DECLARE @peakType VARCHAR(5) = 'Peak1'; 

    WHILE @currentDate <= (SELECT MAX(dateTime) FROM Peak)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Peak_fact (DataDate, peak, peakType)
            SELECT
                p.dateTime AS DataDate,
                MAX(p.SA_data) OVER (ORDER BY p.dateTime ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS peak,
                @peakType AS peakType
            FROM 
                Peak p
            WHERE 
                p.dateTime BETWEEN @currentDate AND DATEADD(DAY, 6, @currentDate);

        SET @currentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @currentDate); -- Skip 7 days 
        SET @peakType = CASE @peakType WHEN 'Peak1' THEN 'Peak2' WHEN 'Peak2' THEN 'Peak3' ELSE 'Peak1' END; -- Cycle peak types
    END;
END;
```

But the result is incorrect, because for the Table 1

| Value | Date | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1/1/2023 | Start 1 |
| 15 | 1/2/2023 |  |
| 13 | 1/3/2023 |  |
| 11 | 1/4/2023 |  |
| 10 | 1/5/2023 |  |
| 5 | 1/6/2023 |  |
| 31 | 1/7/2023 | End 1 / Peak |
| 9 | 1/8/2023 |  |
| 31 | 1/9/2023 |  |
| 21 | 1/10/2023 |  |
| 22 | 1/11/2023 |  |
| 34 | 1/12/2023 |  |
| 8 | 1/13/2023 |  |
| 5 | 1/14/2023 |  |
| 33 | 1/15/2023 | Start 2 / Peak |
| 22 | 1/16/2023 |  |
| 9 | 1/17/2023 |  |
| 18 | 1/18/2023 |  |
| 19 | 1/19/2023 |  |
| 22 | 1/20/2023 |  |
| 29 | 1/21/2023 | End 2 |
| 10 | 1/22/2023 |  |
| 9 | 1/23/2023 | Start 3 |
| 8 | 1/24/2023 |  |
| 29 | 1/25/2023 |  |
| 33 | 1/26/2023 |  |
| 55 | 1/27/2023 |  |
| 81 | 1/28/2023 | Peak |
| 3 | 1/29/2023 | End 3 |
| 88 | 1/30/2023 |  |
| 44 | 1/31/2023 |  |
| 10 | 2/1/2023 |  |
| 20 | 2/2/2023 |  |
| 44 | 2/3/2023 |  |
| 83 | 2/4/2023 |  |
| 69 | 2/5/2023 | Start 4 |
| 99 | 2/6/2023 | Peak |
| 20 | 2/7/2023 |  |
| 40 | 2/8/2023 |  |
| 10 | 2/9/2023 |  |
| 32 | 2/10/2023 |  |
| 33 | 2/11/2023 | End 4 |
| 83 | 2/12/2023 |  |
| 63 | 2/13/2023 |  |
| 92 | 2/14/2023 | Start 5 / Peak |
| 65 | 2/15/2023 |  |
| 42 | 2/16/2023 |  |
| 84 | 2/17/2023 |  |
| 21 | 2/18/2023 |  |
| 23 | 2/19/2023 |  |
| 12 | 2/20/2023 | End 5 |
| 92 | 2/21/2023 |  |
| 65 | 2/22/2023 | Start 6 |
| 74 | 2/23/2023 |  |
| 83 | 2/24/2023 | Peak |
| 10 | 2/25/2023 |  |

The output should be what is in Table 2:

| date | Value | Peak |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/7/2023 | 31 | peak1 |
| 1/15/2023 | 33 | peak2 |
| 1/28/2023 | 81 | peak3 |
| 2/6/2023 | 99 | peak1 |
| 2/14/2023 | 92 | peak2 |
| 2/24/2023 | 83 | peak3 |

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on "peak" is is some largest value?  What is meant by "within 7 days"?  1/15 to1/28 is more than 7 days for instance.  I assume you did not mean "daze" here (humor, laugh a bit :) )  FWIW Sample data might help here

Comment: Please **do not** use images for data. Use tabular markdown

Comment: Peak = maximum value, so for example the maximum value from the first seven days=31 then from this maximum value i will skip seven days … peak 2 will be the maximum value within the seven days after the skip.

Comment: The problem is that sql server throws error when i try to use window functions

Comment: (edit/repost) You can perhaps define a local +/- 7 day peak using window functions as `WHERE Value = MAX(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 FOLLOWING) AND Value > MAX(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`. (The second condition selects the first of a plateau of consecutive equal peak values or first in a set of closely grouped peaks.) You could then feed that into logic that orders by peak value descending and selects the top N values.

Comment: "Sql server throws error" doesn't give us much to go on if you are looking for help. What error? Post the exact message. Also it may help is you post the SQL Server version you are using. Execute the command `select @@version;` and post the first line of the results back here.  And don't forget to repost your sample data as a table or text that we can cut & paste. This is needed so we can test any potential answers.

Comment: "sql server throws error ..."  What error???  Where it it???

Comment: The `WHERE Value = MAX(Value) OVER(...)` I posted in an earlier comment logic was untested because I had no usable data to work with. I now realize that that was likely the error your were referencing. I have a correction to that (using a subselect) and also have suggestions to fix your original logic, but am awaiting usable sample data to test with.  If you are having problems with formatting the data, just post it as raw text and someone here can help reformat it.

Comment: Perhaps the explanation is flawed, or the expected results. If we're talking fixed seven day windows then why isn't there a `2023-01-12  34  peak2` result?

Comment: not a fixed seven days, the days will change based on the peaks.

Comment: The posted data has been formatted into a table. I took the liberty of adding a "notes" column to the source data showing the start/end or each range and the resulting peaks within those ranges.  Note the the start of each range after the first is 8 days after the the chosen peak of the prior range (skipping 7 days).

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches that you can consider. One fixes up your current stored procedure to produce your posted desired results. The second uses a more traditional definition of a local maximum.

Your original stored procedure had several issues that I have fixed up below.

1. The original logic did not have a `WHERE` condition to exclude rows that were not peak rows. This caused all dates in the selected range to be inserted into the results, instead of just the selected peak. To fix this, the `MAX()` window function logic was moved to a subselect and a `WHERE s.SA_data = peak` condition was added to the outer. I also added a `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` to pick just the first peak date if there are multiple peak value matches.
2. The `@CurrentDate` logic was adding 7 to the current value instead of calculating a new start based on skipping 7 days following each selected peak. Fixing this requires capturing the selected peak date and using it for both the results insert and the updated `@CurrentDate` calculation - `SET @currentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 8, @Datadate)`.
3. The `(SELECT MAX(dateTime) FROM Peak)` ending value calculation for the `WHILE` loop was moved to a variable to avoid repeated/redundant queries. This doesn't affect the results, but improves performance slightly.
4. The `MAX()` window function logic is already contained in a query that limits the rows to the desired 7-day range, so a separate `ROWS BETWEEN ...` qualifier is unnecessary and has been dropped. The remaining empty `OVER()` qualifier then just refers to the entire 7-day range. This doesn't affect the results, but simplifies the code.

The updated stored procedure would then be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPeaksAndInsertIntoPeakFact 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(dateTime) FROM Peak); -- Initialize starting date
    DECLARE @lastDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(dateTime) FROM Peak);
    DECLARE @peakType VARCHAR(5) = 'Peak1'; -- Initialize peak type

    WHILE @currentDate <= @lastDate
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Datadate DATE;
        DECLARE @peak INT;
      
        SELECT TOP 1
            @Datadate = s.dateTime,
            @peak = s.peak
        FROM (
            SELECT
                p.*,
                MAX(p.SA_data) OVER() AS peak
            FROM Peak p
            WHERE p.dateTime BETWEEN @currentDate AND DATEADD(DAY, 6, @currentDate)
        ) s
        WHERE s.SA_data = peak
        ORDER BY s.dateTime;

        INSERT INTO Peak_fact (DataDate, peak, peakType)
        VALUES (@Datadate, @peak, @peakType);

        SET @currentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 8, @Datadate); -- Skip 7 days 
        SET @peakType = CASE @peakType WHEN 'Peak1' THEN 'Peak2' WHEN 'Peak2' THEN 'Peak3' ELSE 'Peak1' END; -- Cycle peak types
    END;
END
```

Results:

| DataDate | peak | peakType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-07 | 31 | Peak1 |
| 2023-01-15 | 33 | Peak2 |
| 2023-01-28 | 81 | Peak3 |
| 2023-02-06 | 99 | Peak1 |
| 2023-02-14 | 92 | Peak2 |
| 2023-02-24 | 83 | Peak3 |

As an alternative more traditional local peak calculation, you can define a peak as a point where the current value equals or exceeds all other values within a sliding +/- 7-day window (or chose your window size). In the case of level plateaus having one or more adjacent or closely-spaced equal peak values, the earliest can be chosen.

```
SELECT
    s.dateTime AS DataDate,
    s.SA_data AS peak,
    CONCAT(
        'Peak',
        (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.dateTime)) - 1) % 3 + 1)
        ) AS peakType
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(p.SA_data) OVER(
           ORDER BY p.dateTime ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ) AS Max7Before,
        MAX(p.SA_data) OVER(
           ORDER BY p.dateTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 7 FOLLOWING
           ) AS Max7After
    FROM Peak p
) s
WHERE s.SA_data > s.Max7Before
AND s.SA_data >= s.Max7After
ORDER BY s.dateTime;
```

The above logic will not select a peak from among the middle of a (mostly) continuously ascending or descending series of values. Only when the values form a true local maximum (within a +/- 7 day window) will a peak value be selected.

Results:

| DataDate | peak | peakType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-12 | 34 | Peak1 |
| 2023-02-06 | 99 | Peak2 |
| 2023-02-14 | 92 | Peak3 |

Notes:

- 2023-01-07 (31) was not selected because a larger value (34) exists for 2023-01-12 (+5 days).
- 2023-01-12 (34) was selected because that is a true local maximum.
- 2023-01-15 (33) was not selected because a larger value (34) exists for 2023-01-12 (-3 days).
- 2023-01-28 (81) was not selected because a larger value (88) exists for 2023-01-30 (+2 days).
- 2023-01-30 (88) was not selected because a larger value (99) exists for 2023-02-06 (+7 days).
- 2023-02-06 (99) was selected because that is a true local maximum.
- 2023-02-14 (92) was selected because that is a true local maximum.
- 2023-02-21 (92) was not selected bacause it is equal to the 2023-02-14 value (-7 days).
- 2023-02-24 (83) was not selected because a larger value (92) exists for 2023-02-21 (-3 days).

Adjusting the window size to a range other than +/- 7 days may increase or decrease the number of detected local maximums.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LIUkzYTS) for a demo of both approaches.